# How to check if a C++ type has been defined (in order to provide alternative definition)

Tags: c++

Let's say I have this declaration:

```
void FN(int a) { };

typedef void (*FNtype) (int a);
FNtype X = FN;
```

So now X is a pointer to my function FN. But I want to handle a situation X hasn't actually been defined by providing a replacement. Something like:

```
FNtype X;
if (IFDEFINED(FN)) X = FN; else X = FN_Which_Is_Always_Defined;
```

Is there something like that in C++ ? I can do that with macros, but that would be quite a lot of work...

Comment: It depends. Is `FN` wrapped within a macro to know its existance?

Comment: Hint: Function pointers can be set to `nullptr`.

Comment: I can define a macro to check for it, but as I said that would be a lot of work, as there will be many of these functions. NULL doesn't help obviously, since I don't know if the type exists and I want to assign it, so I'd cause a compiler error. It would be fine to have a macro that would return NULL if the function has not been defined though.

Comment: You want to check if the function `FN` has been defined before you assign to it?

Comment: Yes! I want to be able to assign a function to a variable, but if the function has not been defined, then I want to assign a different one, or NULL.